# that = $(this) for a setTimeout closure not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I want to use `setTimeout` in a button `mouseout` and refer to `$(this)`(the button) from the `setTimeout`. I'm using `that = $(this)`, then use `that`in the `setTimeout` but it doesn't work quite like expected.

If you go hover over each link slowly it works (1,2,3). But if you do it in fast, under 100ms, I get all 3s (3,3,3).

My guess is the closure is not working and the `that` var gets overwritten but i just can't figure out why.

Could you explain what's happening?

```js
$("nav a")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    //
  })
  .mouseout(function(event) {
   that = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){
          console.log( that.data('uid') );
        }, 100);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="3">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `that` to be a local variable (using `var`):

```js
$("nav a")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    //
  })
  .mouseout(function(event) {
   var that = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){
          console.log( that.data('uid') );
        }, 100);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="3">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In you current code, `that` is a global variable, and with each `mouseout` you override it to be the new element.

Comment: That's good to know. I thought `var` didn't matter as long as it's defined within the scope of a function. Thank you!

Comment: `var` is not "just" for there. It has meaning and usage (as explained in my answer). You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is being hoisted to a global without the var keyword. You should consider using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid this in the future.

Edit: As @Dekel pointed out in the comments, strict mode won't actually fix your problem, but would error out when you attempt to declare a variable without the var keyword. It's just a good practice to help avoid this type of unexpected behavior.

```js
'use strict';

$("nav a")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    //
  })
  .mouseout(function(event) {
   var that = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){
          console.log( that.data('uid') );
        }, 100);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-uid="3">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You got my vote for the `use strict`, even though it will not fix his problem, it would only break his code (which will force him to fix it). You should add an explanation regarding that (or link to some other source).

Comment: Thanks both! Could never get in the habit of using strict precisely because it breaks my code :) haha